# hide the next day event in a calendar

Tags: javascript

So I am working on a project where I am creating a site where people can get recipes and cooking tips. I have a calendar that shows the recipe featured  for that day but, I didn't want the next day or days recipe to show up until that day comes is that possible?

Comment: what have you tried? any existing code that you can show?

Comment: share your code?